# Build Sequence to create a PDF with citations from .bib

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, texmaker

I seem unable to configure TexMaker's quick build so that if I have a .bib file, and a .tex file in a directory, and I click 'Quick Build' once, I get a PDF.

Can someone either tell me the sequence of commands I need to run, or the ordered list of commands I need to include in the wizard?

And I would like it to work both from a clean state and when files like .bbl,.aux,.blg or anything already exist.

(I'm using MikTex 2.9)

Comment: After LaTeXing once, run BibTeX, and then LaTeX twice more. See [this](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=usebibtex) for an explanation.

Comment: That works, but it gives me a DVI, how do I get a PDF?

Comment: Alternatively, F1, F11, F1, F1. You only need to do this when you cite an additional publication for the first time.

Comment: Ah, you can use `pdflatex` in the place of `latex` to get a pdf directly, just substitute it into the sequence I gave you for the desired result. :)

Comment: Thanks pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex was what I was looking for!

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 2):

The preferences panel for QuickBuild has a button called "LatexMk + View PDF" that should be what you need, at least if your TeX distribution is TeX Live (I don't know if MiKTeX provides `latexmk`).

For MiKTeX, you can try activating the button "User" and writing in the box

```
texify --pdf --tex-option=--synctex=1 %.tex
```

Comment: OK, tried that, but I get "latexmk: The Perl interpreter could not be found."

Comment: What operating system and TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, 64-bit, MikTex 2.9

Answer (score 0):

I have both texmaker and miktex 2.9. It is very simple. You just have to go to the Option/configure Texmaker panel, and click on the Quickbuild button (on the left hand side of the window that appeared). You then click simply on the pdflatex+view PDF option. 
Then, when you compile, you just have to do Quickbuild, Bibtex, Quickbuild and Quickbuild again. (of course, as you will see, it is also possible to summarize everything in one go by defining a custom Quickbuild instead of one of the options).